# Loading user control with <%@ Register NameSpace %> won't load user control .ascx file but .ascx.cs file instead

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to load User Control from another project, And I like to do it with it's name space:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="IPGostar" Namespace="IPGostarPorject" Assembly="IPGostarPorject" %>
```

but this way when I use this server tag:

```
<IPGostar:DataGrid runat="server" ID="DataGrid1"></IPGostar:DataGrid>
```

the Page_Load of the DataGrid.ascx.cs will load but the content of ascx file won't load.
It's like this tag only calls the cs file and not the ascx file at the first place..

In this case, is it okay to load a .ascx user control file inside a cs file? (for example on Page_Load function we render the ascx file) and if it is okay how can I do that?
Second am I on the wrong path here?

Comment: I think you may be on the wrong path here. If you're hitting the page_load in ascx.cs then your probably loading the ascx as well. You might try adding some basic html to your ascx page to see if it's rendering anything onto your page, or try debugging the page to see if it's being rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look into loading the control using [`Page.LoadControl()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.loadcontrol.aspx).

At runtime, the ascx inherits from the class defined in the ascx.cs. They are not the same thing. The control defined in the ascx is a subclass of that in the ascx.cs.

If you want to distribute a control entirely as a binary, you will need to rewrite it as a ServerControl rather than a UserControl with an ascx.

You can't render the ASCX from the Page_Load of the class in the code behind. That won't work how you are thinking it might.

Answer (score 1):

Modfiy register tag to something like

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="IPGostar" TagName="IPGostar" Src="DataGrid.ascx" %>
```

If you are using a user control you have to specfiy the Source file. Your syntax holds good for custom controls.